# Checking checkbox inside Autocompletion with MUI

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

```
[
  { label: 'First', checked: false }, 
  { label: 'Second', checked: true }
]
```

Here is a very short snippet of how the data could look like.
I am using Material UI's Autocomplete, to make it possible for searching on labels.
These labels are having a checkbox.

Problem is, I can't use `onChange` on `<Checkbox />` when its a `renderOption`
The Autocomplete just closes, without doing any action

```
<Autocomplete
  disableCloseOnSelect={true}
  options={array}
  getOptionLabel={option => option.label.toString()}
  renderInput={params => (
    <TextField
      {...params}
      fullWidth
      label="Select label"
      variant="outlined"
      error={false}
    />
  )}
  renderOption={opt => (
    <div>
      <Checkbox
        checked={opt.checked}
        onChange={() => alert('not being fired...')}
      />
      <p>{opt.label}</p>
    </div>
  )}
/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't use `onChange` in `Checkbox`, You should use `onChange` prop of `Autocomplete`, and set default value by `value` prop
and `Checkbox` receive its props from `renderOption`'s props

```
const [selectedOptions, setSelectedOptions] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
   setSelectedOptions(options.filter(op => op.checked));
}, []);

<Autocomplete
   options={options}
   value={selectedOptions}
   onChange={(event, newValue) => {
      setSelectedUsers(newValue);
   }
   renderOption={(props, option, { selected }) => (
       <div {...props}>
          <Checkbox checked={selected} />
          <p>{option.name}</p>
        </div>
   )}
   disableCloseOnSelect
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

`onChange` event will work in Checkbox provided in renderOption function but it only works when you click on checkbox not anywhere else on list item. You can use `onClick` on the parent div if that fulfills your purpose.